# How to create a visio file dynamically using console application with built-in references?

Tags: c#, .net, package, console-application, visio

I'm working on .net c# technology and am not able read/write a visio file and save it to a particular directory or path as specified.

But i can create a file with .vsdx extension using the following:
" Package package = Package.Open(packagePath, FileMode.Create) "

Basically this open function creates a new package in case it don't find any existing package.

Actually there is something called a package class which is nothing but a zip package in visio it's .vsdx file, this is nothing but a container which stores multiple data objects.
The VSDX format uses Open Packaging Conventions (OPC), which is based on XML and uses a .ZIP container to package all the drawing contents.

Comment: what have you tried , can you re-phrase your question to explain what your blockers are?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you just need to put some contents to that package. Microsoft has an article regarding this:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/visio/how-to-manipulate-the-visio-file-format-programmatically

Please note that unlike Word `DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing` or Excel `DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet`, specialized OpenXml package (library) for Visio does not exist. Means, you'll need to work with plain xml basically. I'd say it's not hopeless, but definitely not an easy task.